# Experience on Facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, chatbot, rasa

I'm new to RASA so, I wonder if we can using experience on Facebook messenger by RASA. 
I need to use **Generic Template**.
If yes please let me know how can I acheive that?

Answer (score 1):

For questions regarding Rasa, you could head to the forum for more detailed answers. Here is a related issue, does this help? https://forum.rasa.com/t/facebook-generic-templates/12303

Comment: I need more details step by step